# Socrata Metadata API Authorization Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, socrata, soda

I am attempting to update my entire metadata asset inventory via python using the Socrata Metadata API. Using the python code example from the Metadata Api Docs, I was able to read the metadata, but I am unable to update it due to Error 403 even with proper Authentication. I have administrator access, access to the secret token, and app token. I have attempted to use both OAuth2 and Basic Authentication to no avail. Here is a quick code sample:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

values = """
  {
    "name": "Business Entities in Colorado_TEST",
  }
"""

headers = {
  'X-Socrata-Host': 'data.colorado.gov',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'OAuth {REDACTED}'
}
request = Request('https://data.colorado.gov/api/views/metadata/v1/4eit-nuxn', data=values, headers=headers)
request.get_method = lambda: 'PATCH'

response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

Where {REDACTED} is equal to App Token less curly braces. In lieu of 'Authorization' I have also tried 'X-App-Token' to no avail. I feel like this is a pretty basic fix, but I'm definitely missing something.

I also attempted to enter a base64 string using:

```
username = '{REDACTED}'
password = '{REDACTED}'
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
```

Added the variable base64string to my headers and ran into the same issue. Based on: [Update a Socrata dataset using app token and private in HTTP basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476917/update-a-socrata-dataset-using-app-token-and-private-in-http-basic)

Here's my Traceback if it's of any help:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    response_body = urlopen(request).read()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the authentication error and have done so by using requests on Python 3 instead of using urllib2. Here is my updated code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding: utf-8
import base64
import json
import requests

username = '{REDACTED}'
password = '{REDACTED}'
string = '%s:%s' % (username, password)
base64string = base64.b64encode(string.encode())
app_token = '{REDACTED}'

values = """
{
  "metadata" : {
    "id" : "TEST",
    "name" : "Business Entities_TEST"
  }
}
"""

headers = {
  'Accept': '*/*',  
  'X-Socrata-Host': 'data.colorado.gov',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic {REDACTED}',
  'X-App-Token': app_token
}

request = requests.get('https://data.colorado.gov/api/views/metadata/v1/4ykn-tg5h', data=values, headers=headers)
request.get_method = lambda: 'PATCH'

response_body = request.json()
print(response_body)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTTP Basic Authentication, which it looks like you are based on your second code sample, you want to use the `Basic` authorization type instead of `OAuth` in your header. Ex:

```
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-Socrata-Host': 'data.colorado.gov',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic {REDACTED}'
}
```

https://dev.socrata.com/docs/authentication.html

Comment: I just changed over my code to read the way you have it here. I am running into the same issue.

headers = {
  'X-Socrata-Host': 'data.colorado.gov',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic {REDACTED}'
}
HTTP Error 403

Comment: I just had another thought on this... Does data.colorado.gov use single-sign-on? If so, make sure you're using the email/password set within your account page, and not your single-sign-on password.

Comment: Thanks for checking back in, Chris. I tried all sorts of combinations to no avail. I think the better solution, at least on my end was to use the requests library and Python 3 as noted in my answer. Katie has added this to the existing documentation.